# High resolution angular position (~0.5 degree) measurement

Tags: raspberry-pi, encoder, digital-potentiometer, rotary, position-sensor

I am attempting to replace a light/mirror sensor to measure the slight low speed oscillations/ rotations of a disc over a period of time. I want to record the angular position, but I wanted to find a method that will allow me to record 0.5 degree movement (at minimum). (Similar shown below [image: Oscillation measurement]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I am currently considering:

- Potentiometers, but I am have difficulty getting the resolution I need. (Everywhere is saying potentiometer resolution is "nearly infinite" but I am not very sure what that means..)
- Encoders/ resolvers(?), but I only need 1 turn and encoders, with their price + max rpm seems like overkill
- I have had suggestions RVDT, but I do not know how I would attach it on this set up.

Comment: Why does a laser and mirror setup not work for you? As far as I know, this is one of the most accurate ways out there for measuring angles.

Comment: A rotary optical encoder with 1024 pulse per revolution shouldn't be too expensive.

Comment: @hearth I am having a lot of trouble with reading the reflected laser and I have tried (and failed) at getting a proper data readout from data sensors.. any you might recommend?

Comment: I've never used a laser+mirror sensor, I just know a bit about metrology.

Comment: Please do not completely change a question to something entirely different.

Comment: try using an optical computer mouse to measure the rotation of the disk

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to measure angular displacement. I have had success with both variable capacitance (using the sub-pF changes to control a VCO, and then counting the resulting frequency) and magnet+linear Hall sensor (crossed axis, so the Hall output swings above and below the zero that occurs when a bar magnet is pointed straight at it).

However, as it tends to be the best in terms of resolution, accuracy, stability, absence of force back on the experiment, the go-to method that most researchers use **is** the laser+mirror+sensor setup.

Maybe it's worth persevering with a little more. Your comment

> I am having a lot of trouble with reading the reflected laser and I have tried (and failed) at getting a proper data readout from data sensors.

suggests that it's worth concentrating on the sensor side.

The classic laser beam sensor consists of just two photodiodes, and is only intended to detect a reference position, when the intensity of light on the two diodes is equal.

For small deviations from this reference position, you get a monotonic, and generally fairly linear unbalance in the two outputs.

It's possible to extend the array of photodiodes in an arc, and using a multiplexer, read the array to find which pair the beam is between, and then using the ratio between those two, estimate an interpolated position. As you don't need high angular resolution, it might be worth increasing the beam size so that it illuminates more than two diodes. This will allow you to make a more linear interpolation of spot position.

If you don't grok photodiodes, then you could always use LDRs (light dependent resistors), and read the illumination as resistance. They're not as fast, linear, stable or well matched as photodiodes, but I find them a bit more 'friendly'.

You can run into problems if you use a conventional (back-silvered) mirror. It's worth using a 'first surface' mirror, they're fairly inexpensive in small sizes.

Comment: RV Jones in the 1970s built some sensitive capacitor sensors  https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3735/6/7/001

Comment: @DDuck Hmm, pity it's behind a paywall!

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you so much! I will perservere. I have been trying to use a CCD linear sensor (https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/TCD1103GFG8ZAA?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvhQj7WZhFIAO5eL%252b6vQyA6yEnh7ifWa7lGuNSOLjBLyA%3D%3D), but I will try a photodiode array . I know this is not the spot to ask, but would you have any reommendations for a multiplexer/ photodiode aray 
Also, high resolution is the goal, but I am just trying to make a first prototype. I have been looking at conductive plastic potentiometers ("essentially infinite resolution") would using this not be a possible solution?

Comment: If you have a gaussian (or nearly so) beam covering 3 or so sensors, then computing the centre of gravity of the spot, first moment / zeroth moment, will give you a good interpolated position. How to mux diodes? It depends on your required reading speed. One opamp each, and mux their outputs, or mux the diodes to a single opamp with CMOS switches. Plastic pot, if your setup can spare the torque required to turn it, why not!

Comment: @Neil_UK Can't help it if the really useful paper is there. RV Jones just did everything right. https://ore.exeter.ac.uk/repository/bitstream/handle/10871/10661/GoodchildJ.pdf

Comment: @sirlyidk If you want to use a CCD sensor, then consider buying a webcam, plug it into an RPi, and program picture detection in python. Point it at a mirror on the shaft, reflecting a structured image. Align to the mirror-shifted image, and read out angular displacement for <£50.

Answer (score 0):

Put some retro-reflective tape on the shaft and point a laser at it.

Detect the back scattered speckle pattern with a camera (no lens required) and cross-correlate the digital image of the speckle at position 1 and with the speckle pattern at position 2.

If the laser spot on the tape is small, the speckles are large and you might not be able to cross-correlate; if the spot it large the speckles will be so small that they'll be spatially integrated by the detecting pixel and the image will be uniform and you would be able to correlate either. About 0.5 to 0.8 mm is roughly about right (at 635 nm) with the speckles about the size of the pixels.

This will give you the displacement of the pattern and for small rotation angles this is a simple calculation.  The bandwidth of this measurement is limited by the camera frame rate.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but tbh I do not have very much experience with using a camera to read/ process data. Do you have anywhere I can start. (I apologize, I am rather new to all of this)

Answer (score 0):

If you want high resolution (better than 0.1 degrees), I would suggest that you could try the AMS range of magnetic encoders.

For example the [AMS 5047U](https://ams.com/documents/20143/36005/AS5047U_DS000637_1-00.pdf/8639418f-6c3a-1624-4e6f-18f52c962099) allows 0.4 degree resolution with a single magnetic pole pair. With low rotational acceleration you should get better than 0.1 degree repeatability on ABI. The chip maintains the position count which may be an advantage.

[image]

This [application note](https://ams.com/documents/20143/80162/AnglePositionOnAxis_AN000271_2-00.pdf/bd13692b-b589-af7f-560c-4d62bf25d9dd) should show you most of the detail necessary to select a sensor.

If can't get to the end of your shaft for a magnetic solution and don't mind a bit more engineering You could use a glass/metal encoder wheel and an optical grating resolver such as [this](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/AV02-1132EN) unit from Broadcom. These are dirt cheap and can get you to 1000 ppr or 0.36 degree resolution. The accuracy of the glass rotary code wheels is excellent.

[image]

[image]

These sensors are easy to engineer providing you can get the codewheel over your shaft, but you have to count the quadrature transitions externally (the AMS magnetic solution gives you a nice convenient count) yourself. The real benefit here is that you can increase the resolution x4 without difficulty giving the best resolution possible IMO.